# Help with designing nozzle geometry for compressed air thruster

Tags: engines, nozzle, rcs

I am designing a compressed air thruster with a conical nozzle geometry. The general design consists of a compressed air tank, pneumatic tubing, and then the actual chamber with the nozzle. The chamber, and nozzle entrance/exit are planned to be 1" ID, and for now I am designing around 3/8" pneumatic tubing. I used [the formula from here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/nozzles-d_1041.html) to determine the critical pressure ratio. Even though I have gotten to this point, I have ran into a bit of a roadblock with a few different things that don't make total sense to me:

1. Is it problematic if the throat pressure is less than 1 bar? My supply pressure is 10 bar but due to the pressure drop from the pneumatic tubing to the chamber I calculated only 1.4 bar of pressure in the chamber (very low, I know; just trying to start small and safe). Also, does this pressure drop from the tubing to the chamber make sense?
2. How do I determine the throat area needed to give me the optimal throat pressure?
3. How should I select an expansion ratio?

I will also add that this is occurring in a collegiate club environment, I have access to a full machine shop, and I am trained on the 3 axis CNC which I'll be using to machine this. Long term will switch to CO2 and much higher pressure, but again, just starting small and safe.

(Edited to remove incorrect equation)

Comment: You cant use that pressure/area equation to compute pressure drop into the chamber.  It will depend on your flow rate, which will be a function of your throat area. If your throat is smaller than the tube, you’ll likely have negligible pressure drop.  If it is larger, there is a sweet spot where choked flow will be possible contingent on the pressure drop, but it will definitely feature higher chamber pressures than you estimate.  1.4 bar in the chamber with 10 bar reservoir is unrealistic pressure drop for choked nozzle flow unless you regulate the reservoir pressure down significantly.

Comment: Consider the extreme: a pinhole sized throat, then the flow through your chamber and tube is very slow. The pressures in tube and chamber will be nearly equal.  It would be dangerous to design your chamber for 1.4 bar in this case.  I will say again and clearly that this equation: (p1/p2) = (A1/A2) is the issue.  It is totally inappropriate for this system.

Comment: Ok perfect this is exactly what I wanted to see. So would it be fair for me to assume no pressure drop between the pneumatic tubing and chamber as long as the throat diam is <= the tubing diam? If so, how should I size the throat assuming I want the chambers diameter to be 1"?

Comment: I know I have to use the flow rate in some fashion but which specific equation should I use?

Comment: You would assume a chamber pressure (9-10ish bar) and pick either a massflow or thrust, then compute the throat area that gives that thrust/massflow.  If you pick thrust, you’ll want to compute the thrust coefficient the nozzle will provide.  Once you know your massflow, you can compute the static pressure of the air in the tube, this can be used as a rough estimate for the chamber pressure.  Otherwise lookup correlations for pressure drop across a ‘backwards facing step’.  Then recalculate with this new chamber pressure and repeat until the value converges.

Comment: I voted to close because your question is very broad and based on incorrect calculations.  You should try to understand these equations: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/rocket/rktthsum.html

Comment: Also, cold gas thrusters don't need a chamber.

Comment: Ha, very good point that totally slipped my mind, @OrganicMarble

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah I'm aware that it wouldn't have an actual "chamber", but that is just the best word I could think of to describe the volume between the pneumatic tubing and converging section.

Comment: @AMcKelvy What would be the best way to calculate the static pressure in the pneumatic tube? Besides that your answer is exactly what I was looking for and makes total sense.

Comment: @kyle, in the link I provide, you can replace the terms subscripted with “e” with values anywhere in the system. You would need to use the area ratio equation to compute the subsonic mach number in the tube (the equation has a sub and supersonic solution for a given area ratio).  Then plug the Mach number in the tube into the pressure ratio equation to find static pressure.  Though, as organicmarble points out, a chamber serves no practical purpose if there is no mixing or combustion going on.

Comment: But that number crunching is a way to estimate pressure drop, i.e. a way to estimate the total pressure in the chamber.  You will also need to account for pressure drop in your line from the reservoir.  Try looking up the “darcy friction factor”.  If you remove the chamber from your design, all you need to do is compute the pressure loss in the line.  Or just place a pressure regulator close to your nozzle.

Comment: @AMcKelvy Ah ok that makes sense. Yeah I'll put the regulator right before the "chamber". Also, if I were to not have a "chamber", then wouldn't the throat diameter end up excruciatingly small since it would be starting at 3/8"?

Comment: A reasonable assumption is that it is equal to whatever your reservoir temperature is, though I am not 100% on this.  Vessels do funny things when they discharge. It may depend on the size of your reservoir, with smaller tanks possibly resulting in a loss of total temperature at the nozzle upon significant expansion of the original control volume.  I would need to dig into my thermo notes to be sure.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. And then just ideal gas law for vessel temperature drop as it discharges over time (assuming its not near liquefaction conditions)

Comment: @AMcKelvy I think I've gotten a design down for this thruster now. With a chamber pressure of 10 bar, exit diameter of 1" and an expansion ratio of 1.3 I got an exit mach of 1.68, exit velocity of 78.9 m/s, mass flow of 0.136kg/s, and thrust of 13.16lb. Do these numbers seem reasonable?

Comment: Confirm your throat is smaller than the tube diameter.  78.9 m/s seems extremely low unless your temperature is very cold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148374/discussion-between-a-mckelvy-and-kyle).